# Changing name of table which is a copy of a table

Tags: excel, vba

There are 138 tables on a sheet.

I created a userform to insert a new account. I am trying to insert the new account by copying the table to the left and pasting it in numerical order.

How do I change the name of the new table. All tables are named as "Ledger_(Account Number)".

I can find the new table but I can't figure out how to change its name.

```
Sub AddtoLedger()

' This is a test macro to find the correct place for the new account on the Ledger

Dim LedgerAccountCell As Long

Dim tbxAccountName As String
Dim cbxAccountType As String
Dim tbxAccountNumber As Long

Dim AccountName As String
Dim AccountType As String
Dim AccountNumber As Long

Dim NewAccountNumberCellLedger As String
Dim OldTable As ListObject
Dim OldTableName As String

AccountName = CreateNewAccountForm.tbxAccountName.Value
AccountType = CreateNewAccountForm.cbxAccountType.Value
AccountNumber = 1002
'''CreateNewAccountForm.tbxAccountNumber.Value

'More Code Between here that loops through to find the correct numerical order 'to add the new account               

Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ledger").Cells(8, LedgerAccountCell + 9).ListObject.Name
' This gives me the correct name of the new table "Ledger_1001155"
' I am trying to change the name from Ledger_1001155 to Ledger 1002

'This will change the name of the new table that was coppied to have the appropriate name
Set OldTable = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ledger").Cells(8, LedgerAccountCell + 9).ListObject.DisplayName

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ledger").Cells(8, LedgerAccountCell `+ 9).ListObject.Add.Name = "Ledger_" & AccountNumber

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ledger").ListObject.Name = "Ledger_" enter code here& AccountNumber
```

Comment: `TheSheet.ListObjects(oldName).Name = newName`?

Comment: How do I get it to recognize the (oldname)? I tried setting it as a variable but I couldn’t get it to work. Any ideas? Let me clarify too. Because the new table changes names each time I do not know how to get it to retrieve the new table “oldname” and change it to the “new name”.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have an `OldTable` object, the `oldName` is `OldTable.Name`.

Comment: You are amazing. I didn’t know to put the “.name” after oldtable. I’m trying to learn and understand how via works still. You have just solved hours of frustration. I can’t thank you enough. Thank you Mathieu Guindon.